# on_delete=models.PROTECT not working in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a model, called contract, that will have a foreign key to the instance of the user. I don't want the contract to be deleted if the user gets deleted it keeps the contract because of `on_delete=models.PROTECT`. This is my entire model:

```py
class Contract(models.Model):
    # * added by photographer
    model_email = models.EmailField(max_length=240, blank=False)
    shoot_location = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=False)
    shoot_date = models.DateField(default=date.today, blank=False)
    # todo: contract content
    # ? how to add photographer's fist and last name to contract?

    # * added by model
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False)
    model_address = models.CharField(max_length=480, blank=False)
    # todo: signature

    # * added automatically
    photographer = models.ForeignKey(
        User=get_user_model(),
        verbose_name=_("photographer"),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    signed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    # todo add PDF file
    get_url = models.URLField(
        default=secrets.token_urlsafe(64),
        editable=False,
        blank=False,
        help_text="The url emailed to the model to sign the contract."
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.model_full_name} - {self.date_created}"
```

But when I run `makemigrations` I get the following error:

```
  File "/Users/mark/Documents/hannerly-b/hannerly/contract/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Contract(models.Model):
  File "/Users/mark/Documents/hannerly-b/hannerly/contract/models.py", line 25, in Contract
    on_delete=models.PROTECT
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says the missing is 'to' in your ForeignKey. Remove `User=get_user_model()` and replace it by `to=get_user_model()`

Answer (score 0):

You have some ways to referencing the User model. Check this two of them:

Access the user model is via get_user_model:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
   )
```

Another option is access User directly:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```